# Алгоритм игрового автомата

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Никакой коммерческой подоплеки. Я только учусь.
Решил написать игровой автомат, простенький, используя свои знания, а их не много.

Вышло так - три класса, барабан1, барабан2, барабан3. В каждом барабане три метода, позиция1, позиция2, позиция3. В методе просто генератор случайных чисел от 1 до 5. В мэйне проверка - if (барабан1.позиция1 == барабан2.позиция1 == барабан3.позиция1){например ставка увеличивается на 2}, потом проверка второй и третьей линии.

Так как я недавно стал заниматься программированием, конечно же мне хочется улучшить мой божественный код. Я добавил кол-во барабанов до 5. И теперь для победы достаточно что б сыграли три рядом стоящих любых барабана. От трех. Вопрос, как бы вы делали подобную реализацию ? Потому что кол-во if теперь хочет стать очень большим, и превратить мой божественный код в адский отстой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы делал примерно так (в псевдокоде :) :

```
int барабан[N];
...
bool Победа = false;
for(i = 0; i < N-2; ++i)
    if (барабан[i]==барабан[i+1] && барабан[i]==барабан[i+2])
    {
        Победа = true;
        break;
    }
```

Или, если надо `M` рядом стоящих барабанов, можно вместо `if` сделать соответствующий цикл.

Answer (score 1):

Наверно самый простой вариант, который подойдет для N барабанов - класть их в массив, а потом подсчитывать, сколько в массиве есть вхождений того или иного возможного значения барабана.

Для подсчета значений вы можете использовать `Map`, где ключем будет являтся возможное значение барабана, а значением - количество уже подсчитанных барабанов с таким же значением. А потом вы просто перебираете массив с барабанами и увеличиваете `value` в вашей `Map` по ключу, равному значению барабана. После чего смотрите эту `Map` на наличие значения с количеством 3 и больше.

Так можно подсчитать кол-во вхождений каждого значения барабана, если учесть, что важи барабаны уже находятся в массиве `drums`, а `Drum.value` - текущее значение барабана:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
for (Drum drum : drums) {
    if (values.get(drum.value) != null) 
        values.put(drum.value, values.get(drum.value) + 1);
    else
        values.put(drum.value, 1);
}
```

Вариант решения может и громоздкий, но он очевидный, и должен сделать код более читаемым.

Comment: Вхождения не помогут, так как в условии - *для победы достаточно что б сыграли три* **рядом стоящих** *любых барабана*

Comment: Да, забыл совсем. Тогда действительно всего-то нужно сравнивать по три в цикле. Правда этот вариант придется переписывать, если вдруг понадобится сделать 4 рядомстоящих, но думаю, что не принципиально)